# ASP.net Visual Web Developer - Joining Access database with SQL

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, ms-access

I am a relative novice but will try to keep up with your answers!

I currently have a customer database on MS access (2003- gasp!)
I would like to build a asp.net website so that customers can log in online, using asp's login functionality with ms sql database.
I then want to link from the sql database with the login details to the customer data in the access database.

I am very comfortable with access, particularly around building queries to give me the data I want (I understand sql, but find it much easier to use the visual element of access to build the queries)

My question is how would I go about this? Do I need to migrate the database to SQL? If so I might have to recode lots of the functionality I have in the database.

Im am using VWD2012, MS SQL Server 2014 and Access 2003

Answer (score 0):

This example uses MVC, but the idea is the same with the ASP login classs as well. You can  add the unique UserName created by the MS-SQL login to your MS-Access database.

For example, the built-in ASP Registration method will return new validated user information:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel model) {
  SaveUserNameInAccessDB(model.UserName); // An OLEDB function to save UserName in AccessDB - you can also create a cookie with the user name for automatic log-ons.
}
```

When the user logs in, you can use the entered UserName (or cookie) to find the customer in the AccessDB.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult LogOn(LogOnModel model) {
    FetchCustomerFromAccessDB(model.UserName); // OLEDB function to associate UserName with the customer in your Access application.
}
```